# Is "Ambien" kosher for Pesach?

Tags: passover, medicine, chametz-leaven

Is Ambien (taken to help sleep) kosher for Pesach? Also, is there a difference between the Ambien made in USA vs. made in Israel?

Comment: FYI - Per the [Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/cons-appr-obgyn.htm) Ambien CR tablets is considered dairy. I do not know the Pesach status.

Comment: Note to future readers: Drug ingredients change. Any answer here that depends on formulation may therefore be outdated by the time you read it.

Comment: Also, please do not consider information given in answers here, even if recent, a substitute for speaking with your rabbi *and* your doctor. Please do so, perhaps armed with information from answers here, before taking action with respect to altering your medication.

Answer (score 4):

Many are stringent regarding various ingredients that go into the pill, and this is a popular and well-established custom.

Nonetheless, the [Chicago Rabbinical Council policy](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/pdf/crc_passover_2013_meds_cosmetics.pdf) still holds:

> FOR LAWS OF TAKING MEDICINE ON SHABBOS AND YOMTOV, PLEASE CONSULT YOUR RABBI.
>
> - All pill medication -- with or without chametz -- that one swallows is permitted. Vitamins and food supplements do not necessarily fall into this category...

(So let's assume this is discussing *chol hamoed*.)

I have no idea about any particular medication, but my impression is that some of these issues are of less concern in the US, where most fillers are corn-based, whereas in other parts of the world they may be wheat-based.