# Chametz on Pesach in products other than food

Tags: halacha, passover, medicine, chametz-leaven

Is it allowed to have products for cosmetics or medicine which contain elements of what's considered chametz during the Pesach?

Comment: See the OU Guide to Pesach https://oukosher.org/passover/download-passover-guide-signup/?utm_source=SilverpopMailing&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Download%20passover%20guide%202018%20(1)&utm_content=&spMailingID=19191126&spUserID=MjM3MDk4NTQ1NTAS1&spJobID=1183277318&spReportId=MTE4MzI3NzMxOAS2

Comment: I haven't yet seen the current guide. But basic rules change little from one year to the next. I recall their guide says to check perfumes and esp. lipstick as they tend to contain ethyl alcohol which is chametz. They and other guides around publish a list of which OTC medicines you may use. Medicines are tricky, as there are some leniencies to take something that has chametz if you swallow it rather than eat it, if it is not flavored, if you MUST Take it for your health, if there are no substitutes, etc.  (cont.)

Comment: If there is a medication that you must take and it may have chametz, you should of course ask your doctor if you can skip a week or take a non-chametz substitute. If not, then your rav can offer you proper direction. Ideally, a medical rav or have him consult with your doctor to help him make a more informed halachic decision.

Comment: Are you asking about keeping them in your house (vs. selling them to a non-jew), or about using them on Pesach?

Comment: Relevant sources: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57155/3, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56651/3, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26469/3,

Comment: @Ploni about using them, most of the time you keep these products in your house because you need them or use them on a regular basis.

Comment: @Levi Cosmetics & medicines may have different laws (and possibly different opinions). Additionally, as pointed out above, medicines may have some leniencies. Consider narrowing it down or splitting it into two separate questions.